# Kendo bar chart- how to change the first grid color?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

In the example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPUr4/149/   How to change the color of the first grid to some other color? As of now , the entire graph background color is default white. I want to change only color of the grid which has first two bars(both X and Y axis sides)?

Below is the HTML code:

JS code:

```
function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Site Visitors"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column",
                labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    background: "transparent",

                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Total Visits",
                data: series1,
                gap: 1.0,
                spacing: 0
            }, {
                name: "Unique visitors",
                data: series2,
                gap: 1.0
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                min: -200000,
                max: 200000,
                axisCrossingValue: 50000,  
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: "Availability"
                },

                color: 'blue'
            },
            categoryAxis: {
               color: "blue",
                width: 25,
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: true,
                    position: "bottom"
                },
                line: {
                    width: 3,
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}"
            }
        });
    }

var series1=[56000, 63000, 74000, 91000, 117000, 158000];
var series2= [-52000, 34000, 23000, -98000, 67000, 83000];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        createChart();

        $("#example").bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);

        var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart"),
            firstSeries = chart.options.series;
    });
```

** EDITED **
check the image here: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=10pd56s&s=8#.U42n-vmSxN8
 only the block marked in black has to be grey. can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I have not got your requirement clearly, So I have updated all colors in Chart.

```
function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Site Visitors"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column",
                labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    background: "transparent",

                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Total Visits",
                data: series1,
                gap: 1.0,
                spacing: 0,
                color: "#FFFF00"
            }, {
                name: "Unique visitors",
                data: series2,
                gap: 1.0,
                 color: "#FF0000"
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                min: -200000,
                max: 200000,
                axisCrossingValue: 50000, 
                majorGridLines: {
                color: "#00FFFF"
                },
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: "Availability"
                },

                color: 'blue'
            },
            categoryAxis: {
               color: "blue",
                width: 25,
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: true,
                    position: "bottom",
                    color: "#FF00FF"
                },
                line: {
                    width: 3,
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}"
            }
        });
    }

var series1=[56000, 63000, 74000, 91000, 117000, 158000];
var series2= [-52000, 34000, 23000, -98000, 67000, 83000];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        createChart();

        $("#example").bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);

        var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart"),
            firstSeries = chart.options.series;
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPUr4/180/)

[Color Code](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp)

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But it didn't help me. I am looking how to color only the first grid / block in the entire kendo chart with grey? First grid means- the one which has both +ve and -ve bar in the first  block?

Comment: check the image here: http://i58.tinypic.com/10pd56s.jpg   only the block marked in black has to be grey. can this be done?

Comment: can you please add this image in your question? Due to some security reason I am not able to open it.

Comment: for example: consider this example: http://jsfiddle.net/mkCJz/2/

The chart area for the entire graph is set to grey. How can set the background for the first bar only to grey?